# Continuity of the sum of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. How do I show that $h:X\to \mathbb{R}$ where $h:=f+g$ is continuous, would prefer to use the general definition so for and open $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $h^-(U)$ is open. Also if $Y$ is another top space and $k:Y\to \mathbb{R}$ is also a continuous function, how do I show $l:X\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $l:=f+k$ is also continuous. Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You should consider the maps

- $(f,g)\colon X → ℝ × ℝ,\; x ↦ (f(x),g(x))$,
- $f × k \colon X × Y → ℝ × ℝ,\; (x,y) ↦ (f(x),k(y))$, and
- $(+)\colon ℝ × ℝ → ℝ,\; (a,b) ↦ a+b$.

If you can show continuity for all of these maps, you have also shown continuity for $f + g = (+) ∘ (f,g)$ and $f + k = (+) ∘ (f × k)$ (not sure if “$f+k$” isn’t a bit of a misleading notation here).

---

For the continuity of $(+)$: For any $c ∈ ℝ$, every $ε/2$-maximum-ball around any preimage $(a,b) ∈ (+)^{-1}(c)$ stays within an $ε$-ball of $c$ by the triangle inequality. This implies that preimages of open sets are open. (Essentially: $|(a' + b') - (a + b)| ≤ |a-a'| + |b-b'|$.)

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, also preferred strategy is to use the definition that the preimage of open set is open, for the + function you defined know there is a quick way using sequences but not definition I need to use. Thanks again

Comment: @Jens Is that okay?

Comment: One could replace the first bullit point with continuity of the diagonal map $\Delta\colon X\to X\times X$, $x\mapsto (x,x)$. Then $f+g = (+)\circ(f\times g)\circ \Delta$. For the continuity of $\Delta$, the preimage of a basic open set $U\times V$ is $U\cap V$, hence open.

Comment: Not quite sure, how do I know $(+)^-[B(c,\epsilon/2)]$ is the Cartesian product of 2 open balls in $\mathbb{R}$ with radius $\epsilon$, is that what you are saying or am I confusing things. Can you clear things up for me? Thanks again, really appreciate it. Also how do I show that the map $X\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $x\mapsto |f(x)|$ is continuous using just the open preimage definition of continuity?

Comment: @Jens I didn’t characterize the preimage of an open ball around $c$, but I instead said that *any point* in this preimage *has an open neighbourhood within* the preimage. The cartesian products of open sets in $ℝ$ is open in $ℝ × ℝ$. I firmly believe you can show the continuity of the absolute value yourself using the same trick. Ask again if you couldn’t manage to do so.

Comment: No sorry I'm still stuck, my problem is the size of the radius of the open balls, $B(.,.)$. So my understanding is that we want to show for any $(a,b)\in(+)^{-1}[B(c,\epsilon)]$ we have a $\delta>0$ so $B(a,\delta)\times B(b,\delta)\subset (+)^{-1}[B(c,\epsilon)]$, that is for $(z,w)\in B(a,\delta)\times B(b,\delta)$; we have $|z+w-c|<\epsilon$ but $$|z+w-c|\leq |z-a|+|a+b-c|+|w-b|$$ so $\delta=\epsilon/2$ won't work in fact we need $\delta=0$. So I am obviously doing something very wrong, please can you tell me where and if I am understanding it correctly and what must I do. Thanks agaoin

Comment: Prove $B(a,δ) × B(b,δ) ⊂ (+)^{-1}[B(\underline{a+b},ε)]$ instead.

Comment: Thank you, that was an obvious, but I just didn't see it. But am still having trouble with $x\mapsto |f(x)|$ I don't have any open balls in $X$ (as $X$ is an arbitrary top space). So how do I show that for any open $U\subset\mathbb{R}$, $|f|^{-1}(U)$ is open, i.e. $\forall x\in |f|^{-1}(U)\exists$ an open $N(x)$ such that $x\in N(x)\subset|f|^{-1}(U)$. Thanks again and your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This is only true if $f$ is continuous. So show instead that the absolute value $ℝ → ℝ,\; x ↦ |x|$ is continuous. (Well, this actually is almost the definition of the topology of $ℝ$.) Then $|f| = |·| ∘ f$.

Comment: Yes, f is the same continuous function but I wanted to avoid using the fact the composition of continuous functions are continuous as the exercise was just to use preimage definition, even though it's much more clumsy. And yes and not that slow as I know and can easily show |.| is continuous because of reverse triangle inequality lol. But thanks anyway, your help was really apprecited and got me unstuck, thanks again.

Comment: @Jens Well, you can redo the proof that the composition of continuous functions is continuous for your special case. This is sort of only using the preimage definition.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define the shift in x operator:
  \begin{eqnarray}
  S_x : \mathbb{R}^2  &\to& \mathbb{R}^2 \\
    (x,y) &\mapsto& (x + x, y+x)
  \end{eqnarray}

It is easy to prove that this is continuous using open balls.

Pick $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$ then $S_x(x)=(2x, x+y)$. An arbitrary open ball around 
$S_x[(x,y)]$ is $B[ (2x, x+y), r]$,  Now $S^{-1}[B(2x, x+y),r]] = B[(x,y),r]$, 
so $S_x$ is continuous.

Define 
\begin{eqnarray}
h : X &\to& \mathbb{R}^2 \\
    x &\mapsto& (f(x), g(x)).
  \end{eqnarray}

Let us now assume that $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$, and $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous.
We show that
\begin{eqnarray}
f+g : X &\to& \mathbb{R} \\
      x &\mapsto& f(x) + g(x)
    \end{eqnarray}
is continuous.

Since
\begin{equation}
 S_x[h(x)]= [2 f(x), f(x)+g(x)]
\end{equation}
and:

(i) Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous then $h(x)$ is continuous,
      from the product topology continuity of a function is equivalent of continuity of all its projections.

(ii) The function composition is continuous, that is
    $S_x \circ h: A \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous.

(iii) Since $S_x \circ h$ is continuous its components $ 2 f(x)$ and
    $f(x)+g(x)$ are continuous.

So $f+g$ is continuous.