# Showing the subset $\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1 > x_2 \}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The metric is the typical Euclidean metric, $ \sqrt{ (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 } $.

I have solved this one, albeit with in my opinion quite excessive steps. I would love to know if there is a simpler way to do it. Below is my approach.

---

Denote $A = \{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1 > x_2 \}$.

Take $p \in A$ and write $p = (x_1, x_2)$, where $x_1 > x_2$. Want to find a ball around $p$ entirely contained in $A$.

The smallest distance from $p$ to the line $x_2 = x_1$ is $\frac{x_1-x_2}{\sqrt 2}$.

Take any smaller radius, such as $ r = \frac{x_1 - x_2}{10} > 0$. Want to show the open ball $B_r (x) \subset A$.

Let $q \in B_r (x)$ and write $ q = (y_1, y_2)$. Want to show $y_1 > y_2$.

Since $q \in B_r (x)$, we have $\sqrt{ (x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2 } < r$.

This implies respectively

$$|x_1 - y_1| < r \ \ \ \text{  and  } \ \ \ |x_2 - y_2| < r,$$

owing to $|a| \leqslant \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} < r$.

Adding these inequalities we get the condition $ |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2| < 2r $.

Using the symmetry of absolute value, write $|x_1 - y_1| = |y_1 - x_1|$. The triangle inequality in reverse gives us:

$$|y_1 - x_1 + x_2 - y_2| \leqslant |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2| < 2r$$

Exploiting the fact that $2r = \frac{x_1 - x_2}{5} < x_1  - x_2 $, we now write: $$ x_2 - x_1 < -2r < y_1 - x_1 + x_2 - y_2 < 2r < x_1 - x_2 $$

Adding and subtracting $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively, we get:

$$ 0 < y_1 - y_2 < 2(x_1 - x_2) $$

Since $x_1 > x_2$, this inequality is legitimate and shows $y_1 > y_2$. Done.

---

Could there by a simpler way to show this? I found all the inequality juggling somewhat circuitous, which made me wonder whether there is a slightly more shorter and elegant way to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are off to a good start. Here is a shorter version of your argument: let $p \in A$ and write $p = (x_1,x_2)$ so of course $x_1 > x_2$.  Define $r = x_1 - x_2$.

Select $0 < \epsilon < \dfrac r2$. If you are given a second point $q = (y_1,y_2)$ with $|p-q| < \epsilon$ then
$$|x_1 - y_1| \le |p-q| < \epsilon$$
and
$$|x_2 - y_2| \le |p-q| < \epsilon$$
so that
$$y_2 \le x_2 + \epsilon = x_1 - r + \epsilon \le y_1 - r + 2\epsilon < y_1$$
and in particular, $q \in A$.  It follows that $B(p,\epsilon) \subset A$.

This implies every $p \in A$ has a neighborhood contained in $A$ so that $A$ is open.

Comment: Neat! All the other answers are fine too, but I wanted to stay at my abstraction level of inequalities.
I really liked where you went from the split up inequalities $|x_1 - y_1| < \epsilon$ and $|x_2 - y_2| < \epsilon$. My path was a tad bit lengthier and verbose, I like this much more. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can define $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y)=x-y$. This is a continuous function, and $A=f^{-1}((0,\infty))$, the inverse image of an open set. Hence $A$ is open.

Comment: Can the person who downvoted this give an explanation? I don't see a mistake in this solution.

Comment: @mark please show also why $f$ is continuous? Your argument is circular

Comment: because $f(x,y)$ is the difference of two continuous functions

Comment: @Arctic Char Well, this is something I assume OP knows how to check. In details, suppose $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y)$. This implies $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$ and by arithmetic of limits it follows that $f(x_n,y_n)=x_n-y_n\to x-y=f(x,y)$. These are just results from elementary calculus.

Comment: To show that $f$ is continuous, you need to show that $f^{-1} (U)$ is open for all open set. Using sequence, you will need to know the equivalence of the two definitions.

Comment: @Arctic Char In metric spaces the definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @Bernard In my case, about 2 seconds after the answer was posted.

Comment: @ArcticChar: It simply results fro $\mathbf R$ being a topological group. This is part of the basics.

Comment: @Bernard So you need to show that $+ : \mathbb R\times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, which include showing that $\{x_1+x_2 <c\}$ is open.

Comment: @Arctic Char I think you should read a bit about metric spaces. There are $3$ equivalent definitions of continuity ($\epsilon-\delta$, using sequences and the topological definition), and of course we always want to use the one which is the easiest to use in the given exercise.

Comment: @mark You are response to a someone who is working on showing that $\{x_1<x_2\}$ is open. If a students knows about metric spaces and the different definition of continuity, they likely would not need to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: @Arctic Char Maybe OP knows the definitions, but he just didn't think about this solution. It isn't that simple, it takes time until you learn to use such tricks. Anyway, OP gave a solution and asked if there is a different way. This is why I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is as follows: consider the map $f\colon\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1-x_2$. Then $A=f^{-1}\bigl((0,\infty)\bigr)$. So, since $f$ is continuous and $(0,\infty)$ is open, $A$ is open.

Comment: How do we know that $f$ is continuous? Your argument is circular.

Comment: The functions $f$ is continuous because it is the difference of two continuous functions. The function $f_1(x_,x_2)=x_1$ is continuous because, given $(x_1,x_2)\in\Bbb R^2$ and given  $\varepsilon>0$, if you take $\delta=\varepsilon$, then$$\lVert(y_1,y_2)-(x_1,x_2)\rVert<\delta(=\varepsilon)\implies|x_1-x_2|<\varepsilon.$$By the same argument, the function $f_2(x_1,x_2)=x_2$. Is continuous. Why do you claim that my argument is circular?

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/744907/629362) which shows the sum is continuous (from the open set definition). The continuity of $+ : mathbb R \times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is used precisely, and you will need to know that $\{x_1+x_2 <c\}$ is open.

Comment: In order to prove that the sum of two continuous functions $f,g\colon\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is continuous, you can do as follows. Take $(a_1,a_2)\in\Bbb R_2$ and take $\varepsilon>0$. Take $\delta_f>0$ such that $$\lvert(x_1,x_2)-(a_1,a_2)\rVert<\delta_f\implies|f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,a_2)|<\frac\varepsilon2$$and take $\delta_g>0$ such that$$\lvert(x_1,x_2)-(a_1,a_2)\rVert<\delta_g\implies|g(x_1,x_2)-g(a_1,a_2)|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$Now, let $\delta=\min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$.

Comment: Then, if $\lVert(x_1,x_2)-(a_1,a_2)\rVert<\delta$,\begin{align}|f(x_1,x_2)+g(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,a_2)-g(a_1,a_2)|&\leqslant|f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,a_2)|+|g(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,a_2)|\\&<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}So, again, why do you claim that *my* argument is circular?

Comment: Well, let me rephrase my first comment to say that this answer looks circular, and after several comments it look extremely incomplete (you are still missing the equivalence between the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition and the open set definition of continuity, or at least when $U = (0,\infty)$).

Comment: That's a standard theorem about metric spaces. Aren't we allowed to use standard theorems here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ A := \{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1 < x_2 \},$$
then the complement of $A$ is
$$A^c = \{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1 \geq x_2 \}.$$ Showing that $A^c$ closed will show us that $A$ is open.

Let $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq A^c$ be such that $x_k \xrightarrow{d} x $ to some $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ as $k \to \infty$, and represent $x_k = (x_{1,k},x_{2,k})$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $$x_{1} = \lim_{k\to\infty} x_{1,k} \geq \lim_{k\to\infty} x_{2,k} = x_2,$$ we must have that $x_1 \geq x_2$ and thus $x \in A^c$. So $A^c$ is closed, and thus $A$ is open.

> *Note: $d$ is the Euclidean metric.*